# Calculate the limit of a quotient

Tags: limits, analysis

I substituted big numbers in calculator as well as graph it. The limit is 0 instead of 1. I don't know which step goes wrong..

Question: $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{2^n \cdot (\sqrt{4^n+2n} - 2^n)}{n+1}$$

My solution: $$=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2^n\cdot(\sqrt{4^n+2n}-2^n)\cdot(\sqrt{4^n+2n}+2^n)}{(n+1)\cdot(\sqrt{4^n+2n}+2^n)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2^n\cdot(4^n+2n-4^n)\div 2^n}{(n+1)\cdot(\sqrt{4^n+2n}+2^n)\div 2^n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2n}{(n+1)\cdot(\sqrt{1+\frac{2n}{4^n}}+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2}{(1+\frac{1}{n})\cdot(\sqrt{1+{2n}\cdot{(\frac{1}{4})^n}}+1)}$$
$$=\frac{2}{(1+0)\cdot(1+1)}$$
$$=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is accurate and valid, and the limit is $(1)$.

What may be counter-intuitive is the effect on the numerator of the 2nd factor.

For example, when $n = 10$, the numerator becomes

$\displaystyle 2^{10} \times [\sqrt{4^{10} + 20} - 2^{10}]
\approx 1024 \times 0.009766 \approx 9.999.$

---

You have to be careful attempting to calculate the fraction for large values of $n$, with a hand-held calculator.  The calculator won't preserve sufficient significant digits, for large $n$.  For example, my calculator returned a numerator of $0$, for $n = 20$, which is clearly wrong.

---

Another viewpoint, when diagnosing the numerator is that

$$\sqrt{4^n + 2n} \approx 2^n + \frac{n}{2^n}.$$

So, the numerator goes to $n$.

Comment: Thank you!! That solves not just this question but everything...!